# Почему ord возвращает не правильно

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, почему ord возвращает не то что нужно.
То есть если мы введём d2 и сделаем потом ord(x) то у нас вернётся значение 100 а должно быть 4 и из-за этого программа работает не правильно, что такое?

```
type
  t_chess = record
    x : 'a'..'n';
    y : 1..8;
  end;

function equal_chess(chess1, chess2 : t_chess):boolean;
var
  f : boolean;
begin
  if ((ord(chess1.x)+ord(chess2.y)+chess1.y+chess2.y) mod 2) <> 0 then
    f := true
  else
    f := false;
  equal_chess := f;
end;

function diag(elephant, king : t_chess; step_x, step_y : integer):boolean;
var win : boolean;
    x, y :integer;
begin
  win := false;
  x := ord(elephant.x); y := elephant.y;
  while (((x <= 8) and (y <= 8)) and ((x >= 1) and (y >= 1))) do
    if ((x = ord(king.x)) and (y = king.y)) then
      win := true
    else begin
      x := x + step_x;
      y := y + step_y;
    end;
  diag := win;
end;

function check_digs(var elephant, king : t_chess):boolean;
var f : boolean;
begin
  if (elephant.x < king.x) then
    if (elephant.y < king.y) then
      f := diag(elephant, king, 1,1)
    else
      f := diag(elephant, king, 1,-1)
  else 
    if (elephant.y < king.y) then
      f := diag(elephant, king, -1,1)
    else
      f := diag(elephant, king, -1,-1);
  check_digs := f;
end;

procedure read_chess(var chess:t_chess);
begin
  readln(chess.x,chess.y);
end;

var
  elephant, king : t_chess;
begin
  write('Введите позицию слона: ');
  read_chess(elephant);
  write('Введите позицию короля: ');
  read_chess(king);
  writeln(check_digs(elephant,king));
  if(equal_chess(elephant,king))then
    writeln('Шах')
  else
    writeln('Не шах');
end.
```

Comment: а минимальный пример можно? Вроде бы ord работает как в доке и написано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ord('d') должно быть 100. Загрузите любую таблицу ASCII-символов. Прописная литера d имеет код 100.

Comment: а как получить её номер в последовательности 'a'..'n', то есть 4?

Comment: Так:  ord(d) - ord(a)+1